# Remove gap between bootstrap navbar and content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

my `.navbar`style in my local css stylesheet doesn't override the bootstrap predefined one.

Tryin to change the navbar color and remove that gap between it and the content and can't seem to be able to do it.

I've put the local css file below the bootstrap one inside the head tag and that fixed the font override problem I had but it doesn't seem to let me change the other things.

```css
   .bg {
background-image: url(https://s14.postimg.org/whuuxncgh/pexels-photo-247295_16-9.jpg);
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
color: #FFF;

/*    Center text vertically in background image*/
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
    
     <!-- Google Fonts -->
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pinyon+Script" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Dulce Figueiras - Makeup</title>

         <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Local css file -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 5rem;
        }

        .starter-template {
            padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

    
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dulce Figueiras</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Casamentos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Formações</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testemunhos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tabela de Preços</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactos</a>
                </li>
<!--
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
-->
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid bg" id="landingPage">
        <div class="container text-center">
                <h1>Dulce Figueiras</h1>
                <h3>Makeup Artist</h3>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `body {padding-top: 5rem;}` is too much!

Comment: what should I use then. so it wont cut my background image on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use more specific selectors than the ones used by the framework. E.g. for `.navbar` use `nav.navbar`

**EDIT:** In your case, `.bg-dark` class is overriding the red background, remove it from here:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">`

to

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">`

See below:

```css
nav.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: 'Pinyon Script', cursive;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pinyon+Script" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Dulce Figueiras - Makeup</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Local css file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding-top: 5rem;
    }
    
    .starter-template {
      padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark  fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dulce Figueiras</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Casamentos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Formações</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testemunhos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tabela de Preços</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactos</a>
        </li>
        <!--
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
-->
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid bg" id="landingPage">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>Dulce Figueiras</h1>
      <h3>Makeup Artist</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's not working. Changed css like you said. I don't understand why it would work with the font size and family but not with the background color. Edit: fixed the background color problem. Just erased the bg-dark class from the nav in html.

Comment: And the gap problem it seems to be that the bootstrap template comes with a body padding top of 5rem that cuts the top of the background image. But if I erase that the navbar covers the image and I dont want that as well.

Comment: Lol Jose, the `bg-dark` class tweak is specified in the answer. For the gap please share it's code to be able to replicate it otherwise it's blind guess.

Comment: Sorry. Absolute newbie in this.

Comment: Lol no worries, you can edit your post to add the rest of the gap code or create a new one to better isolate it? Either way, if you create a new one please refer me to it from here, and also consider either upvoting this answer if it helped you and/or marking it correct with the green tick. Thank you.

Comment: That's the css for the background image. The problem seems to be with the bootstrap template I used. It has a body top padding of 5rem, which seems to cut the top from my image, but without it the navbar is on top of the image.

Comment: If you provide me a link, I can inspect it and try to help from there :) If you remove the `padding-top: 5rem`, and image pulls up, you can try adding the image `margin-top: 5rem` to push it back down.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import your css style file after the bootstrap.css!

```
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/your.css" rel="stylesheet">
```